# How do I get all the selected option form the optionmenus i created and put it into a list?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am quite new with programming in general and I have a project that I need to write a status of ~50 chips onto an RFID. To begin with I used a loop to create ~50 option menus for the Chip statuses and right now I am having trouble appending the selected options from all the option menus onto a list. All its giving me is the selected option from the very last option menu and I am not quite sure what to do about it.

Any help is appreciated

Here is the code I have so far"

```
from tkinter import *
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

def get_wafer():
    global waferNum
    result = simpledialog.askstring("Wafer Number", "Enter Wafer  Number Here:")
    waferNum = result
    
    
def get_chips():
    global chips_list
    chips= selected.get()
    if chips == 'P':
        chips = '0'
    elif chips=='L' :
        chips='1'
    elif chips=='R' :
        chips='2'
    elif chips=='F' :
        chips='3'
    elif chips=='X':
        chips='4'
    elif chips=='O' :
        chips='5'
    elif chips=='/':
        chips='6'    
    elif chips=='M' :
        chips='7'
    elif chips=='B' :
        chips='8'    
    elif chips=='LO':
        chips='9'
    elif chips=='L/' :
        chips='a'
    elif chips=='LB' :
        chips='b'
    elif chips=='N':
        chips='c'
    elif chips=='S' :
        chips='d'
    elif chips=='NF' :
        chips='e'
    elif chips=='V':
        chips='f'
    else:
        chips=''
    chips_list=[]
    chips_list.append(chips)
    
root= Tk()
root.title("Chips and Wafer")
root.geometry("850x450")



z=1
for x in range(8):
    i = 0
    y = 0
    while i < 12 and y < 12:
        status_opt=['P','L','R','F','X','O','/','M','B','LO','L/','LB','N','S','NF','V']
        selected = StringVar(root)
        selected.set("Status")        
        label_0=Label(root, text = "Chip #"+ str(z))
        label_0.grid(row=y,column=x+1,pady=5,padx=5)
        my_entry= OptionMenu(root,selected, *status_opt)
        my_entry.grid(row=i+1,column=x+1,pady=5,padx=5)
        i = i+2
        y = y+2
        z = z+1 
        
        
            
    
waferButton = Button(root, text="Enter Wafer Number",command = lambda:[get_wafer(),get_chips()],width = 16,height=1)
waferButton.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=5,padx=5)    

saveButton = Button(root, text="Save",command = root.destroy,width = 16,height=1)
saveButton.grid(row=1,column=0,pady=5,padx=5)    

root.mainloop()
print (waferNum)
print (chips_list)
```

Comment: As far as I can see, code chips_list=[] resetting the chip_list to null every time get_chips() function called. So, it's holding only output of last menu option. Just give a try commenting out this line.

Comment: @SamsaniHymavathi I tried it and it just gave me an error thats chip_list is not defined

Comment: Define chips_list=[] outside of the function. It will work.

Comment: I defined chips_list=[] above the def get_chips(): line and defined a new global xy and set xy= chips_list.append(chips) inside the get_chips() function at the bottom and when i try to print xy it just give me "None"